# Convert cooking Shrimp and Vegetables in a foil-packet on a 400 degree grill for 25 - 30 minutes to an oven

Tags: baking

Recipe calls for cooking the shrimp and vegetables in a foil-packet on the grill at 400 degrees for 25 - 30 minutes. I do not have a grill in the city; therefore, I need to use my oven so I'd like to know at what temp and for how long would I bake the foil-packet in my oven.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

400 degrees on the grill = 400 degrees in the oven. No need to make any adjustment.